# ¿Cómo puedo sumar las celdas de una columna en JavaFX?

Tags: java

Estoy realizando un sistema de facturación en `JavaFX` que presenta la información en una `TableView`.

Quiero sumar los números de la columna referente al precio del producto creando una función que pueda invocar al presionar un botón que diga **realizar suma**.

Producto.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package sistema.de.facturacion.modelo;

/* Java Bean
* Clase: Producto  */
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.FloatProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleFloatProperty;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class Producto{
    private IntegerProperty codigo_producto;
    private StringProperty nombreProducto;
    private FloatProperty precioProducto;

    public Producto(Integer codigo_producto, String nombreProducto, Float precioProducto){
        this.codigo_producto = new SimpleIntegerProperty(codigo_producto);
        this.nombreProducto = new SimpleStringProperty(nombreProducto);
        this.precioProducto = new SimpleFloatProperty(precioProducto);
    }

    public Integer getCodigo_producto(){
        return codigo_producto.get();
    }

    public void setCodigo_producto(Integer codigo_producto){
        this.codigo_producto = new SimpleIntegerProperty(codigo_producto);
    }

    public String getNombreProducto(){
        return nombreProducto.get();
    }

    public void setNombreProducto(String nombreProducto){
        this.nombreProducto = new SimpleStringProperty(nombreProducto);
    }

    public Float getPrecioProducto(){
        return precioProducto.get();
    }

    public void setPrecioProducto(Float precioProducto){
        this.precioProducto = new SimpleFloatProperty(precioProducto);
    }

    public IntegerProperty codigo_productoProperty(){
        return codigo_producto;
    }

    public StringProperty nombreProductoProperty(){
        return nombreProducto;
    }

    public FloatProperty precioProductoProperty(){
        return precioProducto;
    }





        public static void llenarDatosProducto(Connection connection, ObservableList<Producto> lista){

        try{

          Statement instruccion = connection.createStatement();
          ResultSet resultado = instruccion.executeQuery("SELECT codigo_producto, " +
                                                         "nombre_producto, "+
                                                         "precio_producto " +
                                                         "FROM tbl_producto");

          while(resultado.next()){

          lista.add(new Producto(

          resultado.getInt("codigo_producto"),
          resultado.getString("nombre_producto"),
          resultado.getFloat("precio_producto")

          ));


          }

        }

        catch(SQLException ex){

        Logger.getLogger(Producto.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);


        }

        }


}
```

Controlador cuyo nombre es  FormularioFacturaController

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package sistema.de.facturacion;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import sistema.de.facturacion.modelo.Conexion;
import sistema.de.facturacion.modelo.Producto;

/**
 *
 * @author lordoracle
 */
public class FacturacionFormularioController implements Initializable {

//Definimos la tabla.

@FXML private TableView<Producto>tblViewProducto;    


//Definimos las columnas de la tabla.


@FXML private TableColumn<Producto,Number> clmnCodigoProducto;    
@FXML private TableColumn<Producto,String> clmnNombreProducto;
@FXML private TableColumn<Producto,Number> clmnPrecioProducto;



//Ahora definimos las colecciones.

private ObservableList<Producto>listaProducto;
private ObservableList<Producto> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


//Preparamos la conexion a la base de datos.

 private Conexion conexion;



 @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

     //Nos conectamos a la base de datos.

   conexion = new Conexion();
   conexion.establecerConexion();

   //Defino el ObservableArray List

    listaProducto = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    //Traemos los datos de la DB y los cargamos en listaProducto


    Producto.llenarDatosProducto(conexion.getConnection(),listaProducto);

    // Finalmente vinculamos Tabla con listaProducto

     tblViewProducto.setItems(listaProducto);
        clmnCodigoProducto.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Producto,Number>("codigo_producto"));
        clmnNombreProducto.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Producto,String>("nombreProducto"));
        clmnPrecioProducto.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Producto,Number>("precioProducto"));



    //Cerramos la conexión.

     conexion.cerrarConexion();

    }    

}
```

Archivo Main

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package ejercicioalumno;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author lordoracle
 */
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    try{


    AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FormularioAlumnos.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    }
    catch(Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();


    }


    }


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }}
```

Comment: Hola Gonzalo, es importante agregues más información o código de lo que  hayas tratado para solucionar esto.

Comment: Ok. Te paso el link de Pastebin donde pego el codigo de la clase Producto con la que estoy trabajando y un controlador que lo que hace es mostrar los datos en un TableView.

http://pastebin.com/05zK1FGC

Lo único que busco en realidad es el modo de crear una función sumar que tome los valores de una de las columnas que traigo de la db mysql que es la que remite al precio del producto...

Comment: En pocas palabras estoy buscando el modo de calcular un subtotal en base a los precios que cargo en esa tabla... Pero no logro descubrir como tomar cada una de las celdas de la columna precioProducto y sumarlas....

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes a disposición el método `getItems()` de `TableView`, lo que te devolverá la lista observable de ítems de la tabla. Luego solo iteras:

```
double total = 0d;
tblViewProductos.getItems().forEach(producto ->
                                    total += producto.getPrecio());
```

Comment: Cual seria la forma para hacerlo de forma automatica? osea sin pulsar el boton, algo parecido a excel